# Do the support sets of subspaces give the representable matroids?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matroid-theory

> **Fact:**   Start with $V$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.  Take the set of all  supports of vectors in $V$.  Throw out $\emptyset$.  You now have the dependent sets of some matroid.

Not sure you believe me?  Or just want to get your hands on the *independent* sets?  (If you tell people that you have a matroid, they always ask you for the independent sets.  How can you blame them?)  Okay, no problem.

Choose a basis for $V^\perp$ and take those vectors as the rows of a matrix $A$.  The sets of indices corresponding to linearly independent columns give the independent sets of the matroid.  (A set of indices corresponds to linearly *dependent* columns, of course, exactly when it can be matched up with nonzero scalars so as to give a vector orthogonal to every row, i.e., a vector in $V$.  This also shows that it doesn't matter which basis you choose.)

It follows from the above that *the matroids that arise in this fashion are precisely the ones that are representable* over $\mathbb R$.

I like this way of thinking about representability.  But I've never seen it presented this way in the literature.  Why not?  (Maybe it has to do with how I seem to be relying on a nice Euclidean inner product?)  This leads me to a couple of questions.

1. Is the fact I stated above presented in any reference anywhere?  I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the direction of one.
2. Is it the case that the fact I stated above remains true when $\mathbb R$ is replaced by any field?  If so, does it characterize representability over any field?

**EDIT:**  I just realized that it's not difficult to prove that the above fact does hold over any field; I believe one can simply show that those support sets which are minimal with respect to $\subseteq$ satisfy the circuit axioms, and that's enough.  So my main question here is whether or not this stills serves to characterize representability over other fields.

Comment: Something's wrong here, if I interpret 'the above fact does hold over any field' as claiming that for any subspace $V\subseteq F^n$, the set of supports of nonzero vectors in $V$ forms the dependent sets of a matroid. The obvious counterexample is the space of vectors of even parity in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, for which the set of supports is not upwards closed. So what exactly is the correct statement?

Answer (score 3):

This is just taking the dual of the usual definition of representability: a representable matroid over a field $k$ is given by $n$ vectors in a vector space $V$, that is by a map $k^n\to V$.  If you dualize, you get a map $V^* \to k^n$ (indeed using the inner product on $k^n$), and the description you gave.  I think it's a little more standard to think about the hyperplanes in $V$ where the coordinates vanish: a set is independent if the intersection of the hyperplanes is transverse (i.e. its codimension is the same as the number of hyperplanes).

I think this interpretation is considered quite standard by people in matroid theory and hyperplane arragnements;  for example, Section 1.9 in these [notes of Reiner](http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Talks/Vienna05/Lectures.pdf) or Section 3 of these [notes by Stanley](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf).  Certainly I tend to think more about matroids in terms of hyperplane arrangements, rather than vectors.

Comment: This does seem to be a useful perspective to keep in mind.  Thanks!